# Angular 9 works as PWA on http://127.0.0.1:8080 but doesn't work on http://192.168.1.197:8080 and Heroku

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm developing a small pet project on Angular 9 and wanted to try converting it into a PWA.
Has followed the guides to do it (in particular, https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/convert-your-angular-app-into-a-pwa-in-2019-the-painless-guide-bbf523d2ce72).

I followed the official guide to run it locally, using an http-server (https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started). The problem is that it works fine, caches requests on http://127.0.0.1:8080, but doesn't register a service worker on http://192.168.1.197:8080 or Heroku, where it is deployed (https://sportbuddies-ui.herokuapp.com).
[image: No service worker on http://192.168.1.197:8080]
No service worker on http://192.168.1.197:8080
[image: Everything works on http://127.0.0.1:8080]
Everything works on http://127.0.0.1:8080

[image: Doesn't work on Heroku]
Doesn't work on Heroku with HTTPS

[image: webmanifest]
webmanifest
[image: ngsw-config]
ngsw-config
[image: app.module.ts]
app.module.ts

Have tried to look for a solution, cleaned cache, rebuilt the project, changed registration strategy in the app.module.ts file. But so far I don't even know what to google, from which side can I start debugging it. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: serviceworker needs https or localhost for registration

Comment: It registers on localhost but doesn't want to register on Heroku with https

Comment: I see in your photos that on heroku you have 5 errors, are they relative?

Comment: no, I have changed Cloudflare account and it simply can not find those images. Has nothing to do with PWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It worked on http://127.0.0.1:8080 but not on http://192.168.1.197:8080 as the first one is localhost, while another one is not (I don't have much experience, can not explain it better), and a serviceworker indeed needs https or localhost for registration.
2. The issue with Heroku was that build was done with `ng build`, while to generate a serviceworker  it should be done with `ng build --prod`.